# How to keep g++ from taking header file from /usr/include?

Tags: g++, c-preprocessor, header-files, zlib

I am building using zlib.h which I have a local copy to v1.2.5, but in /usr/include/zlib.h there is v1.2.1.2.

If I omit adding -I/my/path/to/zlib to my make I get error from using old version which doesn't have Z_FIXED:

```
g++ -g -Werror -Wredundant-decls -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -c -o ARCH.linux_26_i86/debug/sysParam.o sysParam.cpp
sysParam.cpp: In member function `std::string CSysParamAccess::getCompressionStrategyName() const':
sysParam.cpp:1816: error: `Z_FIXED' was not declared in this scope
sysParam.cpp: In member function `bool CSysParamAccess::setCompressionStrategy(const std::string&, paramSource)':
sysParam.cpp:1849: error: `Z_FIXED' was not declared in this scope
```

Alternatively, if I add the include path to the zlib z1.2.5 I am using, I get double defines, it seems as if the zlib.h is included twice with two different sets of -D values, but I don't see how that is happening:

```
g++ -g -Werror -Wredundant-decls -I../../src/zlib-1.2.5 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -c -o ARCH.linux_26_i86/debug/sysParam.o sysParam.cpp
In file included from sysParam.cpp:24:
../../src/zlib-1.2.5/zlib.h:1582: warning: redundant redeclaration of `void* gzopen64(const char*, const char*)' in same scope
../../src/zlib-1.2.5/zlib.h:1566: warning: previous declaration of `void* gzopen64(const char*, const char*)'
../../src/zlib-1.2.5/zlib.h:1583: warning: redundant redeclaration of `long long int gzseek64(void*, long long int, int)' in same scope
../../src/zlib-1.2.5/zlib.h:1567: warning: previous declaration of `off64_t gzseek64(void*, off64_t, int)'
../../src/zlib-1.2.5/zlib.h:1584: warning: redundant redeclaration of `long long int gztell64(void*)' in same scope
../../src/zlib-1.2.5/zlib.h:1568: warning: previous declaration of `off64_t gztell64(void*)'
../../src/zlib-1.2.5/zlib.h:1585: warning: redundant redeclaration of `long long int gzoffset64(void*)' in same scope
../../src/zlib-1.2.5/zlib.h:1569: warning: previous declaration of `off64_t gzoffset64(void*)'
../../src/zlib-1.2.5/zlib.h:1586: warning: redundant redeclaration of `uLong adler32_combine64(uLong, uLong, long long int)' in same scope
../../src/zlib-1.2.5/zlib.h:1570: warning: previous declaration of `uLong adler32_combine64(uLong, uLong, off64_t)'
../../src/zlib-1.2.5/zlib.h:1587: warning: redundant redeclaration of `uLong crc32_combine64(uLong, uLong, long long int)' in same scope
../../src/zlib-1.2.5/zlib.h:1571: warning: previous declaration of `uLong crc32_combine64(uLong, uLong, off64_t)'
```

Here some of the relavent lines from zlib.h referred to above:

```
// This would be line 1558 of zlib.h
/* provide 64-bit offset functions if _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE defined, and/or
 * change the regular functions to 64 bits if _FILE_OFFSET_BITS is 64 (if
 * both are true, the application gets the *64 functions, and the regular
 * functions are changed to 64 bits) -- in case these are set on systems
 * without large file support, _LFS64_LARGEFILE must also be true
 */
#if defined(_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE) && _LFS64_LARGEFILE-0
   ZEXTERN gzFile ZEXPORT gzopen64 OF((const char *, const char *));
   ZEXTERN z_off64_t ZEXPORT gzseek64 OF((gzFile, z_off64_t, int));
   ZEXTERN z_off64_t ZEXPORT gztell64 OF((gzFile));
   ZEXTERN z_off64_t ZEXPORT gzoffset64 OF((gzFile));
   ZEXTERN uLong ZEXPORT adler32_combine64 OF((uLong, uLong, z_off64_t));
   ZEXTERN uLong ZEXPORT crc32_combine64 OF((uLong, uLong, z_off64_t));
#endif

#if !defined(ZLIB_INTERNAL) && _FILE_OFFSET_BITS-0 == 64 && _LFS64_LARGEFILE-0
#  define gzopen gzopen64
#  define gzseek gzseek64
#  define gztell gztell64
#  define gzoffset gzoffset64
#  define adler32_combine adler32_combine64
#  define crc32_combine crc32_combine64
#  ifdef _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
     ZEXTERN gzFile ZEXPORT gzopen64 OF((const char *, const char *));
     ZEXTERN z_off_t ZEXPORT gzseek64 OF((gzFile, z_off_t, int));
     ZEXTERN z_off_t ZEXPORT gztell64 OF((gzFile));
     ZEXTERN z_off_t ZEXPORT gzoffset64 OF((gzFile));
     ZEXTERN uLong ZEXPORT adler32_combine64 OF((uLong, uLong, z_off_t));
     ZEXTERN uLong ZEXPORT crc32_combine64 OF((uLong, uLong, z_off_t));
#  endif
#else
   ZEXTERN gzFile ZEXPORT gzopen OF((const char *, const char *));
   ZEXTERN z_off_t ZEXPORT gzseek OF((gzFile, z_off_t, int));
   ZEXTERN z_off_t ZEXPORT gztell OF((gzFile));
   ZEXTERN z_off_t ZEXPORT gzoffset OF((gzFile));
   ZEXTERN uLong ZEXPORT adler32_combine OF((uLong, uLong, z_off_t));
   ZEXTERN uLong ZEXPORT crc32_combine OF((uLong, uLong, z_off_t));
#endif
// This would be line 1597 of zlib.h
```

I'm not sure how to track this down further.  I tried moving the include of zlib.h to the top and bottom of the includes list of the cpp file, but it made no difference.

An excerpt of passing -E to g++ shows in part:

```
extern int inflateInit2_ (z_streamp strm, int windowBits, const char *version, int stream_size);

extern int inflateBackInit_ (z_streamp strm, int windowBits, unsigned char *window, const char *version, int stream_size);
# 1566 "../../src/zlib-1.2.5/zlib.h"
   extern gzFile gzopen64 (const char *, const char *);
   extern off64_t gzseek64 (gzFile, off64_t, int);
   extern off64_t gztell64 (gzFile);
   extern off64_t gzoffset64 (gzFile);
   extern uLong adler32_combine64 (uLong, uLong, off64_t);
   extern uLong crc32_combine64 (uLong, uLong, off64_t);
# 1582 "../../src/zlib-1.2.5/zlib.h"
     extern gzFile gzopen64 (const char *, const char *);
     extern long long gzseek64 (gzFile, long long, int);
     extern long long gztell64 (gzFile);
     extern long long gzoffset64 (gzFile);
     extern uLong adler32_combine64 (uLong, uLong, long long);
     extern uLong crc32_combine64 (uLong, uLong, long long);
# 1600 "../../src/zlib-1.2.5/zlib.h"
    struct internal_state {int dummy;};
```

Not sure why lines 1566 and 1582 are coming out together in the CPP output, but hence the warning about duplicate declarations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-nostdinc` answers the question in your Q's title -- quoting [this manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc), it means:

> Do not search the standard system
>   directories for header files. Only the
>   directories you have specified with -I
>   options (and the directory of the
>   current file, if appropriate) are
>   searched.

However, I don't think it will solve your actual problem, which seems to be due to two mutually incompatible parts of the same non-system header file getting included -- that feels more likely to be due to some needed `-D` being missing, but I can't say exactly what since I'm not familiar with that specific header file.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that in some instances you have:

`#include <zlib.h>`

and in others you have

`#include "zlib.h"`

You will find the old (system) zlib.h in the first case and the new (user) zlib.h in the second case.

The fix for this is to use `-isystem` instead of `-I` for your new zlib includes, i.e. `-isystem /my/path/to/zlib/includes` instead of `-I /my/path/to/zlib/includes`.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error when compiling leptonica on Solaris 5.10 (64-bit SPARC), and I agree with Alex: some necessary define is missing or something.  On a whim, I added _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 (./configure CPPFLAGS='-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64'), which "worked" (it compiled).  This is a bit of cargo-cult programming of course, 'cause I don't know why I should have had to do that.  I haven't actually tried to use leptonica yet, so it might core or something 'cause I added that define when I built it.